# Socketconnection without Server access

Tags: c, sockets

Basicly a socket connection will be initiated if I have a server socket application... starting with socket,listen and accepting the stream. On the other hand I have a client application starting init. socket,connecting and so on. The server and the client application are either communicating on two different or on one machine.

Presume we have 2 machines is it possible to start a socket connection if I have just access to the client? 
(which means I am able to code on client side a socket application but for no access reasons I can't build up a application on server side.)

Comment: I am refering to libs like libircclient as I presume I start a socketconnection without having socket appllication on server side

Comment: Quite confusing, I'm afraid. If you don't have access to the machine where you want to run a server, then there would be no point in writing a client, would there? What is the purpose of the communication?

Comment: I just want communicate with the server just like for example a bot application... bot is on clientside

Comment: If you could then that would be a bit of a security hole, don't you think?

Comment: Presumably there is _some_ kind of server application that you want to connect to. It doesn't matter what server you connect to, the layout of the client can basically still be the same: Connect followed by any number of receive and send.

Comment: To rephrase, you want to write a client application that connects to an existing server, specifically using the IRC protocol right ? How would that be _not_ possible ? That is the whole point of network programming after all: to make unrelated software on different hosts communicate together.

Comment: your re right but did I missunderstand sth. that in the IRC protocol it is enough to have one application on clientside to build up a socketconnection

Comment: "socketconnection" isn't a word that exist. A connection is basically a communication channel between two end-points. Each end-point is represented by a socket, used by each program. The server creates a listening socket, and waits for clients to connect. The client creates a socket to actively connect to an existing server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean can a client app create a new server socket on a second machine, the answer is no.

Comment: that means on a IRC server must be a socket implicated to ensure a client socket can communicate with it, right ?

Comment: Yes. The server must have a socket actively accepting connections and the client must know the IP address of the server.

Comment: And a port number too unless you are using a protocol such as ping based upon ICMP which is responded by stack in kernel. Also, every program in an IP network which communicates across machines at the lowest level is using sockets. All other methods of communication are built on top of these.